# I need to log in to another user from my Admin account without a password

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-passport

I'm working on a feature that makes it possible for an admin/super-user to select an account from a user list, and then logout from the admin account and immediately log in as the selected user. This must happen without the admin knowing the user's password.

I am using Laravel with Laravel passport alongside Vue, when a user logs in he receives a token with which he can access his role's pages.

I saw that it was possible with `Auth::loginById` but this does not work with Laravel Passport.

In my `AdminController` I have the following function that obviously doesn't work yet.

```php
public function shadowLogin($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id)->first();
        $credentials = [
            'username' => $user->username,
            'password' => ''
        ];

        if (auth()->attempt($username)) {
            $hierarchy = Hierarchy::where('id', auth()->user()->hierarchy_id)->first();

            $token = auth()->user()->createToken('tokenkey', [$hierarchy->hierarchy_name])->accessToken;

            return response()->json(['data' => auth()->user(), 'token' => $token], 200);
        }
    }
```

I expect to eventually be able to 'switch' the currently stored user in vue to 'switch' to the selected User account, redirecting to the home page and being logged in.

Answer (score 0):

change session `user_id` (or load session data with user credentials).